# Dynamic and Synchronous Integration between Power BI and R for Data Analysis and DAX Calculations

Tags: r, powerbi, dax, integration, powerbi-desktop

I'm seeking help with a challenge that involves dynamic and synchronous integration between Power BI and R.

Context:

MTCARS dataset from R saved in Excel.
Dataset imported into Power BI with visualizations and filters created.
Goal:

Create a dynamic selection set of variables in the Power BI table.
Pass the selected variables to R for analysis:
Correlation
Hierarchical clustering
linear regression
Plot the analysis results in Power BI.
Return some results of the variables from R to Power BI for DAX calculations.
Requirements:

Dynamic and synchronous integration between Power BI and R.
Automatic update of results in Power BI when modifying variables in the table.
Questions:

What's the best approach to achieve dynamic communication between Power BI and R for this scenario?
Are there any specific tools or libraries that facilitate this integration?
How can I plot the analysis results from R in Power BI dynamically?
How can I return the results of the variables from R to Power BI for DAX calculations?
Additional Details:

Experience with R and Power BI is preferred.
Code examples and/or relevant documentation are highly appreciated.
Thank you for your attention and I eagerly await your responses!

Obs.: Remember to replace "your_table_name" with the actual name of your table in Power BI.

Sample Code:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Get selected variables from the dinamic table ou table in PWBI
selected_variables <- "your_table_name" # exemple: Pwbi return  mtcars[,c(1,3,4,5,6,7)] 

# Perform analysis in R
correlation_results <- cor(selected_variables)
hierarchical_analysis_results <- hclust(dist(selected_variables))
variable_names <- names(selected_variables)
dependent_variable <- variable_names[1] 
independent_variables <- paste(variable_names[-1], collapse = " + ")
formula_str <- paste(dependent_variable, "~", independent_variables)
linear_regression_results <- summary(glm(as.formula(formula_str), data = selected_variables))

# Return results to Power BI
correlation_results
hierarchical_analysis_results$labels
linear_regression_results
```